# How to increment i in the loop for using python to select different column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, increment

I would like to know how could be possible to create a loop for in Python 3 to increment the values of i, j, k ... for a specific application.

I need to select different columns but they cannot be select with themselves. Let's suppose that my dataframe has 7 columns. I will put an example bellow.

The idea is to create a selection like that:

```
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[0, 3]
[0, 4]
[0, 5]
[0, 6]
 ...
[0, 3, 6]
[0, 3, 7]
[0, 4, 5]
[0, 4, 6]
[0, 4, 7]
[0, 5, 6]
[0, 5, 7]
[0, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 7]
 ...
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

After some replies, I could be able to create the following code:

```
from itertools import combinations 
numbers = [] 
A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
for i in range(8): 
   for combo in combinations(A, i+2): 
      numbrs.append(combo)
```

The output is:

```
[(0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (0, 4), ...
```

How could I use those numbers as index of a iloc iterator ?

For examples, the numbers generated must substitute the code:

```
df.iloc[:,[i, j, k, ...]]
```

Then I will be able to interact among the columns

Comment: Use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) with different `r` lengths (e.g. `range(2, number_of_columns+1)`

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to do but this sounds a lot like a job for `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: Thank you, I would like to print the exactly numbers inside the square brackets that I mentioned.

Comment: @Alambek logic here , if you have [1,2]....[1 7] why you do not have [1,2,3]....[1,2,7]

Comment: The index of the dataframe `df.iloc[:,[0, 1, 2, 3]]` must be accessed using the i,j,k... generated by the intertools `df.iloc[:,[i, j, k, ...]]`

Comment: @Wen-Ben You are right ! There are more index than I posted! It is bigger than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using `itertools.combinations` and `itertools.chain`:

```
import itertools as it

list(it.chain(*(it.combinations(range(8), r) for r in range(2, 9))))
```

Or using a list comprehension if you prefer:

```
[x for r in range(2, 9) for x in it.combinations(range(8), r)]
```

This produces the following output:

```
[(0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (0, 4),
 (0, 5),
 (0, 6),
 (0, 7),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (1, 5),
 (1, 6),
 (1, 7),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (2, 5),
 (2, 6),
 (2, 7),
 (3, 4),
 (3, 5),
 (3, 6),
 (3, 7),
 (4, 5),
 (4, 6),
 (4, 7),
 (5, 6),
 (5, 7),
 (6, 7),
 (0, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 3),
 (0, 1, 4),
 (0, 1, 5),
 (0, 1, 6),
 (0, 1, 7),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (0, 2, 4),
 (0, 2, 5),
 (0, 2, 6),
 (0, 2, 7),
 (0, 3, 4),
 (0, 3, 5),
 (0, 3, 6),
 (0, 3, 7),
 (0, 4, 5),
 (0, 4, 6),
 (0, 4, 7),
 (0, 5, 6),
 (0, 5, 7),
 (0, 6, 7),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 2, 5),
 (1, 2, 6),
 (1, 2, 7),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (1, 3, 5),
 (1, 3, 6),
 (1, 3, 7),
 (1, 4, 5),
 (1, 4, 6),
 (1, 4, 7),
 (1, 5, 6),
 (1, 5, 7),
 (1, 6, 7),
 (2, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 5),
 (2, 3, 6),
 (2, 3, 7),
 (2, 4, 5),
 (2, 4, 6),
 (2, 4, 7),
 (2, 5, 6),
 (2, 5, 7),
 (2, 6, 7),
 (3, 4, 5),
 (3, 4, 6),
 (3, 4, 7),
 (3, 5, 6),
 (3, 5, 7),
 (3, 6, 7),
 (4, 5, 6),
 (4, 5, 7),
 (4, 6, 7),
 (5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 3),
 (0, 1, 2, 4),
 (0, 1, 2, 5),
 (0, 1, 2, 6),
 (0, 1, 2, 7),
 (0, 1, 3, 4),
 (0, 1, 3, 5),
 (0, 1, 3, 6),
 (0, 1, 3, 7),
 (0, 1, 4, 5),
 (0, 1, 4, 6),
 (0, 1, 4, 7),
 (0, 1, 5, 6),
 (0, 1, 5, 7),
 (0, 1, 6, 7),
 (0, 2, 3, 4),
 (0, 2, 3, 5),
 (0, 2, 3, 6),
 (0, 2, 3, 7),
 (0, 2, 4, 5),
 (0, 2, 4, 6),
 (0, 2, 4, 7),
 (0, 2, 5, 6),
 (0, 2, 5, 7),
 (0, 2, 6, 7),
 (0, 3, 4, 5),
 (0, 3, 4, 6),
 (0, 3, 4, 7),
 (0, 3, 5, 6),
 (0, 3, 5, 7),
 (0, 3, 6, 7),
 (0, 4, 5, 6),
 (0, 4, 5, 7),
 (0, 4, 6, 7),
 (0, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3, 5),
 (1, 2, 3, 6),
 (1, 2, 3, 7),
 (1, 2, 4, 5),
 (1, 2, 4, 6),
 (1, 2, 4, 7),
 (1, 2, 5, 6),
 (1, 2, 5, 7),
 (1, 2, 6, 7),
 (1, 3, 4, 5),
 (1, 3, 4, 6),
 (1, 3, 4, 7),
 (1, 3, 5, 6),
 (1, 3, 5, 7),
 (1, 3, 6, 7),
 (1, 4, 5, 6),
 (1, 4, 5, 7),
 (1, 4, 6, 7),
 (1, 5, 6, 7),
 (2, 3, 4, 5),
 (2, 3, 4, 6),
 (2, 3, 4, 7),
 (2, 3, 5, 6),
 (2, 3, 5, 7),
 (2, 3, 6, 7),
 (2, 4, 5, 6),
 (2, 4, 5, 7),
 (2, 4, 6, 7),
 (2, 5, 6, 7),
 (3, 4, 5, 6),
 (3, 4, 5, 7),
 (3, 4, 6, 7),
 (3, 5, 6, 7),
 (4, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 5),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 6),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 4, 5),
 (0, 1, 2, 4, 6),
 (0, 1, 2, 4, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 5, 6),
 (0, 1, 2, 5, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 3, 4, 5),
 (0, 1, 3, 4, 6),
 (0, 1, 3, 4, 7),
 (0, 1, 3, 5, 6),
 (0, 1, 3, 5, 7),
 (0, 1, 3, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 4, 5, 6),
 (0, 1, 4, 5, 7),
 (0, 1, 4, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 2, 3, 4, 5),
 (0, 2, 3, 4, 6),
 (0, 2, 3, 4, 7),
 (0, 2, 3, 5, 6),
 (0, 2, 3, 5, 7),
 (0, 2, 3, 6, 7),
 (0, 2, 4, 5, 6),
 (0, 2, 4, 5, 7),
 (0, 2, 4, 6, 7),
 (0, 2, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 3, 4, 5, 6),
 (0, 3, 4, 5, 7),
 (0, 3, 4, 6, 7),
 (0, 3, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 6),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 7),
 (1, 2, 3, 5, 6),
 (1, 2, 3, 5, 7),
 (1, 2, 3, 6, 7),
 (1, 2, 4, 5, 6),
 (1, 2, 4, 5, 7),
 (1, 2, 4, 6, 7),
 (1, 2, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 3, 4, 5, 6),
 (1, 3, 4, 5, 7),
 (1, 3, 4, 6, 7),
 (1, 3, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
 (2, 3, 4, 5, 7),
 (2, 3, 4, 6, 7),
 (2, 3, 5, 6, 7),
 (2, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6),
 (0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6),
 (0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7),
 (0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
 (0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7),
 (0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7),
 (0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7),
 (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply; I am using the following code: `from itertools import combinations
numbers = []
A = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i in range(8):
    for combo in combinations(A, i+2):
        numbrs.append(combo)`

Comment: But now I cannot be able to run the numbers generated with the iloc command. Like this way: `df.iloc[:,[i, j, k, ...]] `

Comment: @Alambek `i + 2` runs until `9` but your sequence has only 8 elements. Also `it.combinations` returns tuples so you need to convert to `list` for usage with `iloc`.